# How to downgrade visual studio code update?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There seemed to be an update yesterday on my visual studio code and now some things don't work properly. For example, double clicking on a plot doesn't open it in a new tab that I can zoom into.

How can I revert the update?
I looked through several similar questions [here1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49346733/how-to-downgrade-vscode), [here2](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/601456/how-can-i-downgrade-to-the-prior-version-of-vs-201.html), [here3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707698/how-to-downgrade-visual-studio-2017-3-to-2017-2/61476148), but when I go on the visual studio code [website](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_57) I don't see any update that recently happened-- the last one was in May.

Comment: No. The 1.57.xx releases are just called "May 2021". But the last update (1.57.1) for this version was on June 17. The only way to downgrade AFAIK is to uninstall and reinstall an older version.

Comment: How can you find the version before that? Was there a 1.57.0? The only previous one I see was in April

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/releases Not sure if they provide binary release there as well